# How to create our own plugins in adobe indesign

Tags: java, plugins, adobe, adobe-indesign

I want to create my own plugin, Is there any tutorial available. I want to do it in java.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you to start from here: http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/InDesign_Plug-in_Editor

Programming knowlege is required.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for ur reply, link was very useful. I have successfully built the sample from sdk, but i dont know how to connect that sample plugin in indesign. I have checked with indesign CS4 and CS5. I didnt get any "plugin" menu in indesign IDE between "view" and "windows" menus. Can you pls tel me where to find the .pln file or how to get the "plugin" menu in indesign.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

C++ would be required to develop a plug-in for InDesign. It uses Microsoft Visual Studio on Windows and xCode on Mac.

Here is the document http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/plugin/getting-started.pdf

Comment: The link is broken.